# Matrix "Layer" Rotation

Tags: java, matrix, rotation

Consider a matrix of order m*n.

It has l layers.

I need to rotate each layer in anticlockwise direction.

---

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3Sgo.png)

---

This is the code I came up with.

```
        int a1=0; // a1,a2,a3,a4 are counters which start at beginning and the end of each row and column and are then moved to the next layers
        int a2=m-1;
        int a3=n-1;
        int a4=0;
        for(int j=0;j<l;j++) // l is the layers of the matrix
        {
            c=rotate(a,a1,a2,a3,a4);
            a1++;
            a2--;
            a3--;
            a4++; 
        }
```

And this is the rotate method, which rotates the array passed,which is a, by 1 unit

```
public static int[][] rotate(int a[][],int a1,int a2,int a3,int a4){
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(j==a1 && i<a2)   
                c[i+1][j]=a[i][j]; 
            if(i==a2&& j<a3) 
                c[i][j+1]=a[i][j];
            if(j==a3 && i>a4)   
                c[i-1][j]=a[i][j];
            if(i==a4 && j>a1)     
                c[i][j-1]=a[i][j];}}
    return c;}
```

Note that c is a global variable, which is the 2D array to be printed.

This works fine for a single rotation.

But I need to rotate the matrix 'r' times.

For this I tried this,

```
for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        int a1=0;
        int a2=m-1;
        int a3=n-1;
        int a4=0;
        for(int j=0;j<l;j++)
        {
            c=rotate(c,a1,a2,a3,a4); // c was initialized to a 
            a1++;
            a2--;
            a3--;
            a4++; 
        }  
    }
```

But this gives a very weird output where most of the spaces are filled with the integer 2.

Is there a simpler way of doing so? I was thinking of replacing c[i+1][j] with c[i+r][j] in rotate(), i.e replacing 1 by r in rotate() but even this gave a weird output with zeroes in some places.

```
public static int[][] rotate(int a[][],int a1,int a2,int a3,int a4){
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(j==a1 && i+r<a2)   //a1,a2
                c[i+r][j]=a[i][j]; 
            if(i==a2 && j+r<a3) //a2,a3
                c[i][j+r]=a[i][j];
            if(j==a3 && i-r>a4)   //a3,a4
                c[i-r][j]=a[i][j];
            if(i==a4 && j-r>a1)     //a4,a1
                c[i][j-r]=a[i][j];}}
    return c;}
```

How should I resolve this?

Comment: You can start by giving meaningful names to the variables. it is amazing how complex problems become easy when the code is readable to humans

Comment: really? I don't see any meaningful editing

Comment: @SharonBenAsher What else do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very high-level overview of how I solved the problem. Maybe not the most efficient solution, so let me know if you can improve.

1. We should use modulo to "rotate" the matrix, so first form an array of rings, starting from the outermost ring and finishing with the innermost.

   [image]

   Here I defined a few key points on the ring: `top_right`, `bottom_right`, and `bottom_left`, where each point corresponds to an index on the ring. Use these points to decide where on the matrix you map your points from.
2. Now reconstruct the matrix from the array of rings, using the `rotations % ring_length` as the pointer, just like you would do with regular array rotation.